# how do I reverse the order of my images being pulled in and displayed on my website with PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to change the order of my results largest number first

```
 <?php $files = glob("blog/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>
```

Comment: I you want to sort your $files array: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: What do you mean by "largest" number?  Are you looking for an alphanumeric sort?

Comment: Ok mike i have my files saved image_0001, image_0002, image_0003 I will be dumping images in on the regular and in sequential order so i need the newest to be first when pulled to display

Comment: @cheesemacfly this is the right idea i think.  do i put in a seperate php call?

Comment: <?php $files = glob("blog/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count(arsort($files)); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; echo '<img src="'.$num.'" class="blog-img" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>

Comment: You need to call `$files arsort(files)` before running your loop because it returns a bool.

Comment: <?php $files arsort(files) = glob("blog/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; echo '<img src="'.$num.'" class="blog-img" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>

Comment: like that? because it stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just reversing the order of the loop?

```
<?php $files = glob("blog/*.*"); $i = count($files) - 1; for ($i; $i>=0; $i--) { $num = $files[$i]; echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use
`array_reverse ($files)` to reverse the order of the values of the array... then use the loop you are currently using

Comment: this seem to make the most sense, can you show me the syntax?

Answer (score -1):

If you are storing the image in mysql as blob, then you can write an SQL with order by desc clause. example:

```
select image from image_repo order by image_id desc
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL

Comment: yea its just a folder on my server @mike brant